# In Clerk Auth, verify-email-address is not found , 404

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, verify, clerk

i am facing this problem for 2 days and i would be happy if you can help me. Thanks in Advance

and i can provide other codes if it is needed

i am using nextjs and with src . I wanted to make my own route and i am facing this problem now

after i enter my email and press continue it would cause the error

```js
import { SignIn } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import React from "react";
const SignInPage = () => {
    return (
    <>
        <SignIn />
    </>
    );
};
export default SignInPage;
```

[the 404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r0fY.png)

Comment: i am sorry for any mistakes of formatting code. i am new here

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What's your app directory structure set up like? I ran into this problem when I just created a `signin/page.tsx` and `signup/page.tsx`. According to the tutorial, I later changed this to `signup/[[...signup]]/page.tsx` and the signin equivalent. Adding in those extra slugs in the middle fixed it. 

This basically creates catchalls for any subroutes for the top-level signin/signup routes. This'll direct any subroutes to your base signin/signup components, which is what Clerk is expecting to continue handling auth redirects.

Comment: i am not using app directory, i was using src and pages

Comment: Thank @MarkSherer for pointing it out.
It solved a similr issue for me .... not really understanding why that is, but it actually works!

Comment: Awesome @TimoHartmann, glad it helped fixed your issue. Sunnatillo Ro'zmetov, I just meant the directory structure of your app (how is your app organized). The page router still uses the same catch-all routes in nearly the same way.

Comment: @MarkSherer, please do create an answer with your `signup/[[...signup]]/page.tsx` comment. That was very useful to the OP, and to me. And I think that's something easily skipped in the docs, they should emphasize it more.